# Symfony validating embed collection

Tags: validation, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I have embed files collection, everything works fine except validations.

If I'm uploading 3 files and 1 one of them don't pass validation requirements, then another 2 files also won't be uploaded or get, for example, their names saved in DB.

Is there any solution to give that error message on 1 file, but save that another 2 files that are passing validations?

Comment: I have found hacks & solutions for this, I will post answer to this soon !

Comment: You can decide to handle the request any way you want..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a solution for that. If there is an error, your form never get in the state "isValid", and I assume you don't save anything in database until your `$form->isValid()` is true.
You need to handle each file individually, or to add logic in your controller to save valid files, even if your whole form isn't valid (which is not a good Idea I think).

Comment: Yesterday, I've finally understood that. You're definitely right. That's where official tutorials point us to. I will still try to find at least dirty solution, and finally let people know about it. Stackoverflow has a huge amount of question that are similar to this.